# What does “u” in an rpm filename stand for?

Tags: centos, php, yum

I currently have PHP 5.4 installed. These packages are all prefixed with "php54-" (pecl, pear, pdo, fpm, gd, mysql, etc).

I'd like to make the transition to 5.5. The packages are available... however, instead of all being called "php55-", they're "php55u-".

What's the "u" for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely just a differentiator added by the person/group that built the package.  That is *not* one that shipped with the operating system.

The U was likely added so that it would not conflict or be confused with php55 from another source.

A google search leads me to believe it's from [IUS Community Project](http://iuscommunity.org/pages/About.html).  If that's where it's from [this answer in their FAQ](http://iuscommunity.org/pages/FAQs.html#why-are-ius-packages-named-differently) may help you understand.

Another example of this is how webtatic names their version of php55 [php55w](http://webtatic.com/packages/php55/).

Comment: You're right, it is IUS.  I did have a look on their site and couldn't find any clues.

Comment: I forgot to add this link on the original post.. it doesn't specifically mention php55u, but it explains why they name differently.  [FAQ: Why Are IUS Packages named differently](http://iuscommunity.org/pages/FAQs.html#why-are-ius-packages-named-differently)